# Solving a discrete equation

Tags: equation-solving

Suppose `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h` are **different** digits in the range 1 – 8 which satisfy:

$\qquad \frac{b}{a}+\frac{\text{fgh}}{\text{cde}}=1$

How can I find their value? I tried

```
Solve[
  {b/a + FromDigits[{f, g, h}]/FromDigits[{c, d, e}] == 1, 
   1 <= {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} <= 8, 
   Unequal @@ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}}, 
  {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, 
  Integers]
```

but *Mathematica* cannot get the result from this formulation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because there are only

```
8!
```

> 40320

combinations, we can test them all:

```
perm = Permutations@Range@8;

out = #2/#1 + FromDigits[{#6, #7, #8}]/FromDigits[{#3, #4, #5}] ==  1 & @@@ perm;

pos = Flatten@Position[out, True]
```

> {10534, 10679, 15991, 16333, 16963, 37736, 38041, 39464}

```
perm[[pos]]
```

> {{3, 1, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 2}, {3, 1, 7, 8, 6, 5, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 
>     1, 7, 8}, {4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 3, 5, 8}, {4, 3, 6, 2, 8, 1, 5, 7}, {8, 4,
>      3, 5, 2, 1, 7, 6}, {8, 4, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {8, 6, 5, 7, 2, 1, 4, 
>     3}}

Comment: Little violent but work well.Thanks.But I think the `Solve` should can do same thing?

Comment: @yode I don't see how there could be a valid `Solve[]` strategy that can solve this.

Answer (score 6):

I like @corey979 answer, but bunch of  `#[[..]]` doesn't look nice to me. 
Also you can use `Select` to avoid many intermediate steps. A one-liner (kinda long one) could be:

```
Select[Permutations@Range@8, #2/#1 + 
  FromDigits@{#6, #7, #8}/FromDigits@{#3, #4, #5} & @@ # == 1 &]
```

Comment: Thanks, I re-made the function in my answer to be less messy.

Answer (score 5):

```
eqn = b/a + FromDigits[{f, g, h}]/FromDigits[{c, d, e}] == 1;
```

Since the sum of the terms is `1` and each term is positive, then each term must be less than `1`, i.e., `a > b && c > f`. You can gain some efficiency by prefiltering the list of `Permutations` with this simpler criteria.

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

ClearSystemCache[]
```

Without prefiltering

```
(soln = Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} -> #] & /@ 
    Select[Permutations@
      Range@8, #2/#1 + 
          FromDigits@{#6, #7, #8}/FromDigits@{#3, #4, #5} & @@ # == 
       1 &]) // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.201104, {{a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 6, d -> 7, e -> 8, f -> 4, g -> 5, 
   h -> 2}, {a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 7, d -> 8, e -> 6, f -> 5, g -> 2, 
   h -> 4}, {a -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 5, e -> 6, f -> 1, g -> 7, 
   h -> 8}, {a -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 7, d -> 1, e -> 6, f -> 3, g -> 5, 
   h -> 8}, {a -> 4, b -> 3, c -> 6, d -> 2, e -> 8, f -> 1, g -> 5, 
   h -> 7}, {a -> 8, b -> 4, c -> 3, d -> 5, e -> 2, f -> 1, g -> 7, 
   h -> 6}, {a -> 8, b -> 4, c -> 7, d -> 1, e -> 2, f -> 3, g -> 5, 
   h -> 6}, {a -> 8, b -> 6, c -> 5, d -> 7, e -> 2, f -> 1, g -> 4, h -> 3}}}  *)
```

Verifying the solutions

```
And @@ (eqn /. soln)

(*  True  *)

ClearSystemCache[]
```

Using prefiltering

```
(soln2 = Thread[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} -> #] & /@ 
    Select[Select[
      Permutations@
       Range@8, #1 > #2 && #3 > #6 & @@ # &], #2/#1 + 
          FromDigits@{#6, #7, #8}/FromDigits@{#3, #4, #5} & @@ # == 
       1 &]) // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.138858, {{a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 6, d -> 7, e -> 8, f -> 4, g -> 5, 
   h -> 2}, {a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 7, d -> 8, e -> 6, f -> 5, g -> 2, 
   h -> 4}, {a -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 5, e -> 6, f -> 1, g -> 7, 
   h -> 8}, {a -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 7, d -> 1, e -> 6, f -> 3, g -> 5, 
   h -> 8}, {a -> 4, b -> 3, c -> 6, d -> 2, e -> 8, f -> 1, g -> 5, 
   h -> 7}, {a -> 8, b -> 4, c -> 3, d -> 5, e -> 2, f -> 1, g -> 7, 
   h -> 6}, {a -> 8, b -> 4, c -> 7, d -> 1, e -> 2, f -> 3, g -> 5, 
   h -> 6}, {a -> 8, b -> 6, c -> 5, d -> 7, e -> 2, f -> 1, g -> 4, h -> 3}}}  *)
```

The results are identical

```
soln === soln2

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FindInstance[
 b/a + Times[f, g, h]/Times[c, d, e] == 1 && 1 < a < 8 && 1 < b < 8 &&
   1 < f < 8 && 1 < g < 8 && 1 < h < 8 && 1 < c < 8 && 1 < d < 8 && 
  1 < e < 8, {a, b, c, d, f, g, h, e}, Integers]

(*  {{a -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 2, d -> 2, f -> 2, g -> 2, h -> 2, e -> 4}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: The OP explicitly wrote that $a-h$ "are from 1 to 8 and **different** integers"; and `FromDigits` is crucial here.

Comment: @corey979 Right, I do not claim that this is a final solution. OP will look for it himself. But this is a way to try.

Comment: In my view, this answers a completely different question - it's a different equation.

Comment: `fgh` is intended as the numeral with those three digits, not their product.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Then it means that I misunderstood the question. Sorry